# Simple Azure Function in Javascript to use HTTP trigger body in queue

Tags: javascript, azure, azure-functions

So I'm messing about with [Use Azure Functions to automate SQL DW compute level](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-data-warehouse/manage-compute-with-azure-functions) from the MS website... and I've created a HTTP trigger that will send a msg to the queue when hit. I'm very new to Javascript, and I'm wondering how to use the HTTP request 'body' in place of the variable I have below

```
module.exports = function (context, res,) {
    var timeStamp = new Date().toISOString();
    context.log('JavaScript timer trigger function ran!', timeStamp);   
    context.res = { status: 201, body: "Resuming Datawarehouse" };        var operation = {
        "operationType": "ResumeDw"
    }
    context.bindings.operationRequest = operation;
    context.done(null, res);
};
```

Quite simply, I willy have some JSON in my HTTP request body that will hit this trigger, I then want to use only what's in that body for my queue. In this case above, it would replace `var operation =`

Any ideas, please?

Just an FYI, I want it to replace what I already have:

```
    var operation = {
        "operationType": "ResumeDw"
    }
    context.bindings.operationRequest = operation;
```

This is static inside the Function, but I want whatever the HTTP request sends as its body to be sent to my queue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second argument of your function is `req`, not `res`, which gives you access to HTTP request including its body:

```
module.exports = function(context, req) {
    // req.body is a thing
    var operation = {
        "operationType": req.body.operationType
    };
    context.bindings.operationRequest = operation;
    context.res = { status: 201, body: "Resuming Datawarehouse" };
    context.done();
};
```